# Wireless from 54mbps to 1mbps

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I've just changed ISP recently to 20/20 mbit and bought a Linksys WRT610N router to hook up my laptops wireless.

Everything is up and running now and I tested that the speed was as promised. Now, my first laptop runs smoothly, but my second laptop is dropping from 54mbps to 1mbps after about 5 - 10 minutes of regular surfing.

I've tried the following:

Change the channel (tried all of them) on the router

Cloning the MAC addresses on both laptops

DHCP reserved the IP addresses for both laptops

Changing security from WPA-2 to WPA

I'm not the most experienced when it comes to setting up network, so please bear with me ;)

Any input on this problem will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Bo

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth checking that you have the latest drivers for that laptop's wireless adaptor. It could be a bug in the firmware that causes it not to be able to retrain up to a higher speed after it has dipped down due to temporary interference, which updated drivers/firmware may resolve.